# overload operator new(), why constructor is called twice?

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I can`t understand some problems when learning new/delete overload.
Questions:

1. Why new is called before constructor，destructor before delete?
2. Why constructor is called twice when using ::new ?

I've appended the code here:

---

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { 
        cout << "My Class is Constructed ！" << endl; 

    }

    ~MyClass() { cout << "My Class is Deleted ! " << endl; }

     static void *operator new(size_t Size)
    {
        cout << "new call" << endl;
        MyClass *p = ::new MyClass;
        return p;
     }
     static void operator delete(void *p)
     {
         cout << "delete call" << endl;
         ::delete p;
     }

};
int main()
{
    MyClass  *p = new MyClass;
    delete p;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
output:
new call
My Class is Constructed ！
My Class is Constructed ！
My Class is Deleted !
delete call
```

---

Comment: You should not do `::new MyClass` inside `MyClass::operator new`. The purpose of that function is to allocate memory without calling constructors, but you make a constructor call (which is why you are seeing 2 constructor calls - corresponding to your two uses of the `new` expression).

Comment: Re your question 1, obviously storage has to be obtained before an object can be constructed in it;  and the object must be destructed before the storage is released

Comment: @M.M: Answer section is below.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yeah. If someone wants to type my comments out into the answer box and fill out details they're very welcome :)

Comment: @M.M Just curious, although I didn't see your comment before I answered (don't think it was there at the time) why would you comment instead of answer?

Comment: @Curious can do it in 30 seconds... whereas writing an answer with proper formatting and background info etc. takes longer

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this is happening is because when you allocate something with `new`, the allocation and construction happens in two phases.  The first is the actual allocation and the second is construction via placement new.

The overload you have provided is just for allocating memory (hence the `size_t` parameter), but instead you called `new` on the class which will do both steps from above.  You should only allocate the memory in that function.  So change your function to be

```
static void *operator new(size_t size)
{
   return ::operator new(size);
}
```

And you will see the class being constructed only once.

Comment: so ,delete someting  also has two phases, destruction and  free the memory?  why destructor is called only once?

Comment: @JackChen Because you only called it once, just like the constructor is called twice because you called it twice.

Comment: @JackChen EJP is right, if you notice in your overload for `operator delete`, you have called `::delete` on a void pointer, which is just deallocating memory, you have not tried to `static_cast` the void pointer to pointer to `MyClass` and then called the destructor, that's why you only get one destructor invocation